# Can an Orthodox frum woman who keeps tziniut ride a motorcycle?

Tags: halacha, women, clothing, tznius-modesty, vehicles-transportation

Can an Orthodox frum woman who keeps tziniut ride a motorcycle?
If yes, then what type of clothes should she wear to keep her tzniut (knees covered with skirt).

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Talia! Thanks for sharing the question.

Comment: How is this different from a bicycle?

Comment: How is an orthodox frum woman different from any other Jewish woman?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm no expert in the laws and customs of *tznius*, but I imagine there are different customs in different communities. It appears that Talia would like an answer that is consistent with Orthodoxy.

Comment: I feel like I’ve seen a Gemara regarding women riding a camel. Anyone else know what I’m talking about? Because I have no idea where I saw that.

Comment: Pesachim 3a is where the gemara occurs

Comment: We used to call this "A Shonda on a Honda" ;))

Answer (score 3):

A quick search through the Internet shows, as expected, a disagreement among Poskim.

[Rav Eyal Karim](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?whichpage=2&topic_id=2861925&forum_id=771), [Rav Uri (Amos) Sherki](http://ravsherki.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1147:11471147-1147&catid=26&Itemid=100512), and likely [Rav Yaakov Ariel](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/41103) (he is asked a slightly different question) say that it is allowed.  Presumably, one would need to keep the same standard of Tzenius that they always adhere to.

[Rav Revid Nagar](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2861925&forum_id=771), and [Rav Hillel Meyers](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/123878) (in the name of Rav Chanan Afallo) say that it is Assur.

Rav Meyers notes his own (slightly better sourced) Teshuva about riding bicycles found [here](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/107101).  Various Poskim have ruled on that Shaila as well, see [Rav Aviner](http://shlomo-aviner.net/index.php/%D7%A6%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99)'s Heter and [kipa.co.il's answer](http://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%91-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D/), which has a wealth of online links. See [Are women allowed to ride bicycles for transport?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30074/are-women-allowed-to-ride-bicycles-for-transport) as well. (H/t to DoubleAA for making this connection.)  Also related to: [Are women allowed to drive?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59823/are-women-allowed-to-drive)